# Core Data simple get and update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i have a Core Data file with
Categories entity, which have 2 attributes - id and name.

Can someone provide me with a method to get values from those 2 attributes, and to update them. I've tried and failed.

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addCategory:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;

}

-(IBAction)addCategory:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *addCategoryAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Category" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
    addCategoryAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    self.textField = [addCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    self.textField.placeholder = @"Enter category name";
    [addCategoryAlertView show];
}
```

and in the UIAlertView Delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I must add values to those categories.

Here is how i've done it now:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == kAddCategoryButtonIndex) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error;

        //NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [entity setValue:self.textField.text forKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[entity valueForKey:@"name"]);
        [context save:&error];
    }
}
```

And I think it works, but i can't get values from these 2 attributes.

If someone can help me, it's going to be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

returns `NSManagedObject`, not `NSEntityDescription`.

So, do this

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[managedObject setValue:self.textField.text forKey:@"name"];
```

and you should be good to go.